# Proper Isolation of Bridge Networks

Tags: networking, network-interface, qemu, bridge

## Proper Isolation of Bridge Networks

I am trying to set up a private network space, isolated from a public network space.

In the public space, I want my guest OS NIC to get it's IP address via DHCP Server.

Here is the network topology I have in mind:

[image: Network Diagram]

## The Problem

The issue I am having is `ens3` and `ens4` are not properly isolated.  When I start my Guest VM:

```
ens3 IP: 192.168.1.60  <-- Good, ens3 is getting it's IP via DHCP server!

ens4 IP: 192.168.1.61  <-- Uh-Oh, ens4 is also getting IP via DHCP Server.  Networks are not properly isolated!
```

Traffic must be getting from `ens3` to `ens4` **OR** from `br0` to `br1` somehow.

### br0 setup via iproute2

Here is how I set up `br0`  (Should not allow traffic between Host Server & Guest VM):

```
# ip link set eth3 up
# ip link add br0 type bridge
# ip link set dev eth3 master br0
# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
# ip link set tap0 master br0
# ip link set dev br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
# bridge vlan del dev br0 vid 1 self
# ip link set dev br0 up
```

### br1 setup via iproute2

Here is how I set up `br1`  (Allows traffic between Host Server & Guest VM):

```
# ip link set eth2 up
# ip link add br1 type bridge
# ip link set dev eth2 master br1
# ip tuntap add dev tap1 mode tap
# ip link set dev tap1 master br1
# ip link set dev br1 up
```

### Guest VM launch via qemu

Here is my qemu launch command:

```bsh
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -m 4G \
   -enable-kvm \
   -cpu host \
   -smp 2 \
   -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:00:00:05 \
   -net tap,ifname="tap0",script=no,downscript=no \
   -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:00:00:10 \
   -net tap,ifname="tap1",script=no,downscript=no \
   -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on \
   -drive format=qcow2,file=disk.cow,index=0,if=virtio
```

Once my Guest VM is running, I set my taps to up

```
# ip link set dev tap0 up
# ip link set dev tap1 up
```

## Question

How do I properly set up this network using iproute2 to isolate `br0` (`eth3`, `tap0`, & `ens3`) from the rest of the Host Server and my Private Network Space?

Comment: What is `eth2` connected to? Run `tcpdump` on both `tap0` and `tap1`. Do you see the DHCP traffic on both interfaces?